# How to get sourcemaps working for React Css Modules?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-modules, webpack-hmr, react-css-modules

I'm trying to setup a React project with [`react-css-modules`](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules), [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/docs/) and [Hot Module Replacement](https://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement.html). Everything is working like a charm but I can't get the CSS sourcemaps to work.

I followed [this guide](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules#react-hot-module-replacement) to make HMR work. It involves a BrowserSync setup to update the css file after Webpack writes it to disk.

I use (as suggested by react-css-modules) the `ExtractTextPlugin` to extract all of the css:

```js
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style','css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!sass')
}
```

But if I change this to sourcemaps, as suggested [here](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader/issues/7#issuecomment-74791811)

```js
loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap!sass-loader outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap=true&sourceMapContents=true')
```

I get the error: `"root" CSS module is undefined.` in my browser console.

You can find my example repo [here](https://github.com/tiemevanveen/React-Webpack-Playground), but here's the full webpack config I'm using for development.

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var WriteFilePlugin = require('write-file-webpack-plugin').default;

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    bundle: [
      'webpack/hot/dev-server',
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
      './index.js'
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  debug: true,
  devServer: devServer,
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './builds'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/builds/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.OldWatchingPlugin(),
    new WriteFilePlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css', {
      allChunks: true
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style','css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!sass')
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.json']
  }
};
```

How to make the sourcemap work?

Comment: Might sound silly, but what about this? `ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style','css?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!sass?sourceMap')`

Comment: $@##&$ me.. that is indeed working. I would swear I've tried that... Nevertheless thanks a lot. Could you maybe add this as an answer so I can reward you the bounty?

Comment: Added some documentation as well. https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules/pull/72 :)

Comment: Weird.. it only works with `sourceMap` on `css` and without the parameter on `sass` at the end. Doesn't make sense...

Comment: According to the docs [you need to pass both](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader#source-maps). Added an answer. Glad it helped. :)

Comment: Weird.. that both is not working for me... to be continued..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this:

```
ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style','css?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localI‌​dentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!sass?sourceMap')
```

i.e. add the `sourceMap` param to both `css` & `sass` loaders. It said so in [sass-loader docs](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader#source-maps).

Answer (score 2):

This is how I have my css modules set up:

```
'css-loader?modules&sourceMap&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!',
```

Comment: That will work as long as you don't use react-css-modules or don't need hot reloading of those modules. In those cases you need the ExtractTextPlugin.

Comment: @Tieme Thats not true. I apologize for spreading this misconception. I updated the docs (https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules#webpack) and updated the discussion thread on the related topic (https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules/issues/51#issuecomment-181660058).

Comment: Thanks! No problem :)